# how to check if object already exists in a list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list

```
  List<MyObject> myList
```

and I am adding items to a list and I want to check if that object is already in the list.

so before I do this:

```
 myList.Add(nextObject);
```

I want to see if nextObject is already in the list.

The object "MyObject" has a number of properties but comparison is based on matching on two properties.

What is the best way to do a check before I add a new "MyObject" to this list of "MyObject"s.

The only solution I thought up was to change from a list to a dictionary and then make the key a concatenated string of the properties (this seems a little unelegant).

Any other cleaner solutions using list or LINQ or something else?

Answer (score 198, accepted):

It depends on the needs of the specific situation. For example, the dictionary approach would be quite good assuming:

1. The list is relatively stable (not a lot of inserts/deletions, which dictionaries are not optimized for)
2. The list is quite large (otherwise the overhead of the dictionary is pointless).

If the above are not true for your situation, just use the method **[`Any()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx):**

```
Item wonderIfItsPresent = ...
bool containsItem = myList.Any(item => item.UniqueProperty == wonderIfItsPresent.UniqueProperty);
```

This will enumerate through the list until it finds a match, or until it reaches the end.

Comment: The use of a predicate delegate for the list.exists is another solution see below, but if you have huge lists and key value with a dictionary will be much faster as it is a hash table!  Enjoy

Comment: How to check multiple value?

Comment: This solution works only for .NET 5.0+   . Sadly some of us don't have this version available. :-(

Answer (score 122):

Simply use [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
bool alreadyExist = list.Contains(item);
```

Note that it works based on the equality function `Equals`. Check the example of [the link above](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you need to implement `Equals` function.

Comment: This didn't work for me, it always said it doesn't exist

Comment: @Si8 If you are trying to compare objects, you have to be sure that the IEquatable<T>.Equals implementation is implemented properly for your object's type.  Otherwise, you will not be comparing the object contents.  See the Contains link Ahmad indicated for an example of how to implement this.

Comment: list.countains cannot be used here, because it would report true for dev1, dev11, dev111... and so on

Comment: @FranckE - sounds like you don't have IEquatable<T> setup properly for whatever it is you're trying to check Contains against.

Comment: That dont work when it is a list of object but it works when it is a list of string

Comment: in my case i implemented the IEquatable<T> for my class / Interface and run over a list with foreach and used .Exists on each item which works like a charm in that case. I used it to add objects not already in the list which passed certain requirements.

Answer (score 70):

If it's maintainable to use those 2 properties, you could:

```
bool alreadyExists = myList.Any(x=> x.Foo=="ooo" && x.Bar == "bat");
```

Comment: Only from .Net 5 +

Answer (score 10):

Are you sure you need a list in this case? If you are populating the list with many items, performance will suffer with `myList.Contains` or `myList.Any`; the run-time will be quadratic. You might want to consider using a better data structure. For example,

```
 public class MyClass
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }

    }

    public class MyClassComparer : EqualityComparer<MyClass>
    {
        public override bool Equals(MyClass x, MyClass y)
        {
            if(x == null || y == null)
               return x == y;

            return x.Property1 == y.Property1 && x.Property2 == y.Property2;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode(MyClass obj)
        {
            return obj == null ? 0 : (obj.Property1.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Property2.GetHashCode());
        }
    }
```

You could use a HashSet in the following manner:

```
  var set = new HashSet<MyClass>(new MyClassComparer());
  foreach(var myClass in ...)
     set.Add(myClass);
```

Of course, if this definition of equality for `MyClass` is 'universal', you needn't write an `IEqualityComparer` implementation; you could just override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` in the class itself.

Comment: Yes, bool for V was my favourite. For that matter, it wasn't so long ago (eh, about 3 weeks) that HashSet wasn't available to me because I was working on 2.0 code, and I dropped in the Mono implementation of HashSet because it's so darn useful :)

Answer (score 5):

Another point to mention is that you should ensure that your equality function is as you expect. You should override the equals method to set up what properties of your object have to match for two instances to be considered equal.

Then you can just do
mylist.contains(item)

Answer (score 4):

Simple but it works

```
MyList.Remove(nextObject)
MyList.Add(nextObject)
```

or

```
 if (!MyList.Contains(nextObject))
    MyList.Add(nextObject);
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I had first said:

---

What's inelegant about the dictionary solution? It seems perfectly elegant to me, especially since you only need to set the comparator in creation of the dictionary.

---

Of course though, it is inelegant to use something as a key when it's also the value.

Therefore I would use a HashSet. If later operations required indexing, I'd create a list from it when the Adding was done, otherwise, just use the hashset.

Comment: I would only use this if the list of objects was huge since its a hash table and they are great for fast lookups.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quick console app to depict the concept of how to solve your issue.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    public class myobj
    {
        private string a = string.Empty;
        private string b = string.Empty;

        public myobj(string a, string b)
        {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }

        public string A
        {
            get
            {
                return a;
            }
        }

        public string B
        {
            get
            {
                return b;
            }
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<myobj> list = new List<myobj>();
            myobj[] objects = { new myobj("a", "b"), new myobj("c", "d"), new myobj("a", "b") };


            for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!list.Exists((delegate(myobj x) { return (string.Equals(x.A, objects[i].A) && string.Equals(x.B, objects[i].B)) ? true : false; })))
                {
                    list.Add(objects[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

A collection can be used as a dictionary, where the difference is that you don't need to a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime or use late binding. Please note that in this case the key must be a string. In my case the key(number) is integer, but declared as string.
You can create a custom Boolean function to check if the key exists in the list.
There is a good article be Paul Kelly on [ExcelMacroMastery.com](https://ExcelMacroMastery.com)

```
' Function to check if item in the collection already exists
Function Exists(coll As Collection, key As String) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo EH

    IsObject (coll.Item(key))
    Exists = True

EH:
End Function
```

end you can use it like this

```
For i = 3 To lastRow
    
        ' Ignore the Normal areas
        If rg.Cells(i, 1).value <> "Normal" Then
        
            number = rg.Cells(i, 1).value
            
            ' Check if the area exist in the collection using a custom function Exists
            If Exists(coll, number) = False Then
            
                Set oRiskArea = New clsHighRiskArea
                oRiskArea.number = number
                coll.add key:=oRiskArea.number, Item:=oRiskArea
                
            Else
                Set oRiskArea = coll(number)
            End If
            
            With oRiskArea
        
                .name = rg.Cells(i, 2).value
        
            End With
            
        End If

    Next i
```