# trying to find if a string is in a list of objects

Tags: python

I'm not sure if this is possible as having trouble finding and answer online, could be as I don't know have to work the question. so the code below is a basic example of what I am trying to do.

```
class Names():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

>>> i = []
>>> i.append(Names("bob"))
>>> i.append(Names("jill"))
>>> i
[bob, jill]
>>> "bob" in i
False
```

I have a list of the Name class and want to return True if a name already exists in there. If know how I could get this working?

Comment: do `print([type(h) for h in i])` and you will see why `False` is returned. Or simply notice that there are no quotes (`bob` .vs. `'bob'`)

Comment: Look on this topic here you can find your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435089/how-to-check-if-object-already-exists-in-a-list

Comment: @KrzysztofPacholski Wrong language?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you could do this.

The easiest is to iterate through with `any`:

```
any(item.name == 'bob' for item in i)
```

The more complex version is to define an `__eq__` method on your class:

```
def __eq__(self, val):
    return self.name == val
```

and now your original `"bob" in i` code will work.

(For real code, you'd probably want to check in that method if you're between two instances of Names, rather than with a string.)

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking of, using `__eq__`.

Comment: Worth mentioning `__hash__` if you're over-riding `__eq__` as you're making the object unhashable without it https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over your list and check the `.name` attribute of each object against your string.

```
>>> any('bob' == j.name for j in i)
True
```

Comment: I have to imagine that there's a more OOP oriented way of doing this, by overloading some magic method somewhere...

Comment: There is, but I tend to be cautious with how liberally I allow equality to be defined. I tend to reserve that for equality between two objects by checking some subset of their attributes

Answer (score 1):

To point out more detail.

When you ask

```
"bob" in i
```

you are asking if the string `"bob"` is in the list. 
Even if you ask if

```
Names("bob") in i
```

you get False because that exact object isn't in the list.

You can add an `__eq__` method inside you class if you want to treate `Names` with the same `name` as identical:

```
class Names():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other.name
```