# How to compare between two lists of a complex object?

Tags: c#, list

I'm new at programming I want to add student information in the list named **LStudent** but I want to check first if this student doesn't exist before if he doesn't then it will add him, but I have a problem I tried to compare and it gives me syntax error how should I compare between them?

```
public void addStudent (Student S) {

    if (LStudent != S)
    {
        LStudent.Add(S);
        Console.WriteLine("The student added sucssesfuly!");
    }
    else {
        Console.WriteLine("This student is registerd before");
    }
}
```

this is the student class:

```
public class Student : IprintAllInfo
{
    public String ID { get; set; }
    public String Fname { get; set; }
    public String Lname { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }

    public Student()
    {
        ID = null;
        Fname = null;
        Lname = null;
        Email = null;
    }

    public Student(String ID, String Fname, String Lname, String Email)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.Fname = Fname;
        this.Lname = Lname;
        this.Email = Email;
    }

    public string PrintAll()
    {
        String message = " ";
        message += "ID: " + ID + "\n name: " + Fname + " " + Lname + " " + "\n Email: " + Email;
        return message;
    }
}
```

and this is method class that I want to add a student in:

```
public class Methods
{

    public List<Student> LStudent = new List<Student>();

    public Methods()
    {
    }

    public void addStudent (Student S) {
        if (LStudent != S)
        {
            LStudent.Add(S);
            Console.WriteLine("The student added sucssesfuly!");
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("This student is registerd before");
        }
    }

    public void Prin() {
        foreach (var student in LStudent) {
            Console.WriteLine(student.PrintAll());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Does this answer your question? [how to check if object already exists in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435089/how-to-check-if-object-already-exists-in-a-list)

Comment: What is if( LStudent != S )??? Wouldn't it be !LStudent.Any(x => x == S)? Or probably you need !LStudent.Any( x => x.Id == S.Id).